# Generate PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to create this in PHP and separate them with commas, in a mysql query.

```
{
    title : 'Property',
    image : '1-1-thmb.png',
    type : 'For Sale',
    price : '$price',
    address : '$address',
    bedrooms : '$bedrooms',
    bathrooms : '$maxguests',
    area : '$area',
    position : {
       lat : 47,
       lng : 19
   },
   markerIcon : 'marker-green.png'
}
```

Could you please help me how is this possible?

Thanks in advance,

I have tried this:

```
$map_flats = array(
    title => 'Property',
    image => '1-1-thmb.png',
    type => 'For Sale',
    price  => $price,
    address => $address,
    bedrooms => $bedrooms,
    bathrooms => $maxguests,
    area => $area,
        lat => $lat,
        lng => $lng,
        markerIcon => 'marker-green.png'
        );
```

Tibor

Answer (score 2):

This is a JSON array syntax. You can learn about the JSON notation in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/book.json.php) or just try this:

```
$json = json_encode($obj); // Encodes object properties/array to JSON
$obj  = json_decode($json); // Decodes JSON to stdClass object
$arr  = json_decode($json, true); // Decodes JSON as array
```